# What a+=b == c does in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I have this piece of code that has been bugging me the whole day, and I think I need some help with it, here is the code is written in C++:

```
    int main()
    {
        int a = 3, b = 4;
        if (a+=2 == b) {
            cout << a << endl;
            cout << "True" << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The `if` statement will always be true no matter what values of `a` and `b` are, and the value of a will not be changed (i.e. The `cout` for `a` will print the value of a when it is first assigned. However, when I put a pair of parentheses to `(a+=2)`, the code will be executed as I expected. So my question is why does the expression in the `if` statement always be `true`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Operator precedence means `a+=2 == b` will be grouped as `a += (2 == b)`. So `a` is incremented with the result of the comparison between `b` and `2`.

The comparison result is a boolean, so when converted to an integer it will yield `0` or `1`.

Since compound addition (`+=`) also evaluates to the result of the operation, the condition in the `if` statement will check the value of `a` is not `0` after adding `0` or `1` to it. Since `a` is initialized to `3`, the condition is true either way.

Comment: Now that you understand the wacky operator precedence rules, stop writing such "clever" code. Write clearly, such that the intent is evident from just reading the code!

Answer (score 9):

Operator `==` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `+=`. This statement is equal to `a += (2 == b)`. The statement returns new value of `a`, which is true when the new value is not zero.

Value of `a` does not change here, because `2 == b` is false, which is zero when converted to integer.

Answer (score 3):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Your answer is in what is called operator precedence and in the definition of Booleans.

C++ evaluates your if statement conditional in the a specific way. First it evaluates your '==' operator. In most cases 2 will not be equal to 'b' and the == operator will return false. You now have:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    if (a += false) {
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << "True" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This makes little sense until you consider that the Boolean false also is the value 0. You now have:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    if (a += 0) {
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << "True" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

'a' += 0 will always remain the value of a. Thus when outputting you get unchanged 'a' and 'b' values.

If you run the code again with b initialized to 2, as seen here:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 3, b = 2;
    if (a += 2 == b) { // 2 == b becomes true (which is 1); a += 1 is then executed;
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << "True" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You get an output of 3 for 'a'. This is because true is also 1 and then 1 gets added to 'a'.

The reason why the if statement appears to always run is because any nonzero number evaluates to true in the if statement.